# window.scroll to activate class one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, scroll

I incorporated a window.scroll function to activate when animations start on my page. I have three different images, that look like this:

image

image

image

I am wanting them to appear once I scroll to their div. However, for some reason right now, if I go over one of them, the entire sequence starts for all of them.

My window scroll function looks like this:

```
$(function() {


 var oTop = $('.home-img-block', this).offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
    if (pTop > oTop) {
      imgDelaysSlide();
    }
  });
});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
 <div id="home-img-block-section">
  <div id="home-img-blocks">
    <div class="home-img-block fadeBlock1">
      <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
        <img src="/images/test1.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">WEB DESIGN</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">The OD team can see your web design visions brought
        to life, creating a site that promotes your uniqueness through specific functionalities and features.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-block fadeBlock2">
      <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
        <img src="/images/test2new.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">ECOMMERCE</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">Custom built solutions catered towards you end goal. 
        gfdgfdsg greg reg regrfesg fdsg gretswtgy tgreswt treswt trgegfd gsvbd fbgre greasgv drfdg greaag gredr</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-block fadeBlock3">
      <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
        <img src="/images/test3new.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">MARKETING STRATEGIES</div>
        <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">MARKETING STRATEGIES gfdgf fdggs gfsg gfsg gf sgf g  
        gfdsg sdfggfs gfdsgssdfg fdggfds gfdsg gfds gfdgs gf dsgfdsgfgs gfdgfs gtrg resg reg rgesgresrgrg</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Should the `this` in my window.scroll function make these animations start when I hover over the current div class?

`var oTop = $('.home-img-block', this).offset().top - window.innerHeight;
      $(window).scroll(function() {`

Is there anything else I could try to do to call out that specific div, rather than the entire class?

UPDATE  adding `imgDelaysSlide` function

```
function imgDelaysSlide() {


 $('.fadeBlock1').delay(300).animate({
    'left': '0%'
  }, 700);
  $('.fadeBlock2').delay(800).animate({
    'left': '0%'
  }, 700);
  $('.fadeBlock3').animate({
    'left': '0%'
  }, 700);
}
```

Comment: what does this imgDelaysSlide(); function do?

Comment: You're referring to [**Waypoints**](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) -- tracking the position of an element in the window and taking action when it reaches a specific point. Other items such as [**Scrollerama**](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/) use similar logic

Comment: `imgDelaysSlide()` is a slideIn function, so without the animation starting when I scroll to the div, it is basically useless.

Comment: @SOIA is there another way to do it, like I currently am? I really do not want to use a big plugin to create this small effect.

Comment: Well you need to track the element's position. You can freely write your own function to do that using things like `is:visible`, etc. . .  or use a plug in that has been in development for some time and proven.

Comment: this is a demo i did some time ago on how to show or hide a div after you scrolled passed another div -- http://jsfiddle.net/b2sjk9pL/

Comment: @Tasos the demo doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Paul yes it does.. .reduce the output area and scroll it.

Comment: works fine on chrome -- scroll pass the (If you passed this div another div will show/hide) and another div will show -- or reverse to hide

Comment: Gotcha. I had to make the output area very small to see it. I updated my question with my function. Aren't I already doing that?

Comment: @SOIA Do you have any examples of sites using waypoints? I searched for it, but I can't find any thing other than basic tutorials. I just want to see if it is what I am looking for, but I am thinking initially that you were right, so thanks for the recommendation.